# Remove specific char in all strings in a list in c#

Tags: c#, list, replace

I have some strings in a list they are

```
KHIJEFGACDB
KHIJEFGBACD
KHIJEFGBCDA
KHIJEFGCDAB
KHIJEFGCDBA
KHIJGABCDEF
KHIJGABEFCD
KHIJGACDBEF
KHIJGACDEFB
KHIJGAEFBCD
KHIJGAEFCDB
KHIJGBACDEF
KHIJGBAEFCD
```

I need to remove `HIJ` which is available in all strings in the list.

I made a C# program like below

```
foreach (string item in items)
{
    item.Replace("HIJ", "");
}
Console.WriteLine(items.FirstOrDefault().Length);
```

But its still displaying 11 that means the HIJ is not removed. How to solve this and get 8 as the answer.

Comment: `Replace` returns a copy of the string with the replacement done. It does not mutate the string you call it on. Strings are immutable.

Comment: Please [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) next time!

Comment: `items.Select(i=>i.Replace("HIJ","")).DefaultIfEmpty("").Length`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings are immutable in C#. Try

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    items[i] = items[i].Replace("HIJ", "");
```

Also note within

```
foreach (string item in items)
```

`item` cannot be modified. And, BTW, foreach *can not be used to add or remove items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects*. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

As noted, strings are immutable. `string.Replace()` returns a *new string*: it doesn't modify the existing string.

But you can do this in one line using Linq, something like this:

```
string[] items = GetMeSomeItems()
                 .Select( s => s.Replace("HIJ","") )
                 .ToArray()
                 ;
```